# No logs about disconnecting HAProxy(TCP IP)

Tags: tcp, haproxy

Problem: in the cat / var/log/haproxy.log redirected log, only the connections are displayed, and the records are duplicated, how to make a more complete log? Configuration /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:

```
global
 daemon
 maxconn 8192
 log 127.0.0.1 local1
 log 127.0.0.1 local1 info
 log 127.0.0.1 local1 debug
 chroot /var/lib/haproxy
 pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid
 stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats group haproxy mode 660 level admin

defaults
 log     global
 mode    tcp
 balance leastconn
 timeout client      14400s
 timeout server      14400s
 timeout connect     14400s
 retries 3
 option  dontlognull


listen sborka_30001
 log    global
 mode                tcp
 option              tcplog
# option             tcpka
 option              logasap
# default_backend     bck
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What you do you mean by "make a more complete log"? Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want see disconnect.